# Where is Flink's test classes' API documentation (javadoc/scaladoc)

Tags: java, apache-flink, javadoc, flink-streaming

I've noticed, that [the Flink's official javadoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/api/java/) lacks the documentation of classes defined in tests. For example, the great `ProcessFunctionTestHarnesses` [mentioned in the official testing guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/stream/testing.html) isn't a part of javadoc.

Browsing the source code on GitHub it's clear, that the test catalogues contain well-documented source code, e.g. the [`ProcessFunctionTestHarnesses`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/d31bd5af28def3de4e353bb1e667eb7f2973ab6a/flink-streaming-java/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/util/ProcessFunctionTestHarnessesTest.java). But apparently it isn't built or linked anywhere. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Good question, but probably better to ask on the Flink user mailing list, as the people who really know would be most likely to see it there.

Answer (score 0):

Only classes that are annotated with annotations that are themselves annotated with `@Documented` are included in the javadocs. So that means that only classes annotated with

- Experimental
- Internal
- Public
- PublicEvolving
- VisibleForTesting

are included.

The test harnesses are not considered part of Flink's API, and thus are subject to being changed at any time.

BTW, the checkstyle configuration used in the project ensures that all classes have proper javadocs, regardless.